# Dataframe is of type 'nonetype'. How should I alter this to allow merge function to operate?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pulled in data from a number of csv files, as well as a database. I wish to use a merge function to make a dataframe isolating the phone numbers that are contained in both dataframes(one originating from csv, the other originating from the database). However, the dataframe from the database displays as type 'nonetype.' This disallows any operation such as merge. How can i change this to allow the operation?

The data comes in from the database as a list of tuples. I then convert this to a dataframe. However, as stated above, it displays as 'nonetype.'  I'm assuming at the moment I am confused about about how dataframes handle data types.

#Grab Data

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(Cell) FROM crm_data.ap_clients Order By Cell asc;")

apclients = mycursor.fetchall()
```

#Clean Phone Number Data

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
data['phone_number'][index] = data['phone_number'][index][-10:] 

for index, row in data2.iterrows():
data2['phone_number'][index] = data2['phone_number'][index][-10:] 

for index, row in data3.iterrows():
data3['phone_number'][index] = data3['phone_number'][index][-10:]
```

#make data frame from csv files

```
fbl = pd.concat([data,data2,data3], axis=0, sort=False)
```

#make data frame from apclients(database extraction)

```
apc = pd.DataFrame(apclients)
```

#perfrom merge finding all records in both frames

```
successfulleads= pd.merge(fbl, apc, left_on ='phone_number', right_on='0')
```

#type(apc) returns NoneType

The expected results are to find all records in both dataframes, along with a count so that I may compare the two sets. Any help is greatly appreciated from this great community :)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I had a function to rename the column of the dataframe as shown below:

```
apc = apc.rename(columns={'0': 'phone_number'}, inplace=True)
for col in apc.columns: 
    print(col)
```

the code snippet out of the above responsible:

```
inplace=True
```

This snippet dictates whether or not the object is modified in the dataframe, or whether a copy is made. The return type on said object is of nonetype.

Hope this helps whoever ends up in my position. A great thanks again to the community. :)